# Using link_to to Call a Custom Controller Filter Method, and Refresh View with Filtered Results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm still on the learning curve with rails, and seem to have backed myself into a corner.

Scenario:

- There is an Array containing people details (id, first_name, last_name), and the Array contents are displayed in a View (formatted as a table).
- There is a method in the Controller for that View which applies a filter to the array - limiting its output.

### Controller

```
#person_controller.rb

require 'module_file'

class PersonController < ApplicationController
  include ModuleFile
  helper_method :build_list

  def index
  end

  def filter_person
    @filter_criteria = lambda { |person| person.id.nil? }
    redirect_to persons_path
  end
end
```

### View

```
#index.html.erb

<%= link_to "Filter Report", :controller => :person, :action => :filter_person %>

<table>
  <% ModuleFile.build_list.individuals.find_all(&@filter_criteria).each do |person| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= person.id %></td>
  <td><%= person.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= person.last_name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

### Routes File

```
#/config/routes.rb
MyApplication::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :persons do
    collection do
      get :filter_person
    end
  end

end
```

I would like to be able to use a hyperlink on a View to trigger the filtering controller method to filter the Array, and then refresh the View with this filter in place. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I ended up using:

### Controller File

```
# person_controller.rb

require 'module_file'

class PersonController < ApplicationController
  include ModuleFile
  helper_method :build_list

  def index
  end

  def filter_person
    @filter_criteria = lambda { |person| person.id.nil? }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {render '_report_detail', :layouts => 'reports', :locals {:@filter_criteria => @filter_criteria } }
    end
  end
end
```

By sending my filter criteria as a lambda to the format.html render option as a :locals reference, it effectively "filters" the rendered data as it loads the report_detail partial. In the short-term, I am referencing the partial with the leading underscore character so I can leverage an existing layout. I will most likely make the partial load with AJAX in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue once and approached it this way:

```
# my_model_controller
class MyModelController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def query
    # Bring a json with the queried array of xxx
    render :json => MyModel.find_all {|i| i.attribute == params[:query]}
  end
end
```

```
//  my_model_script.js
$.get("/persons/query", {
  query: $query // query parameters
}, function(data) {
  console.log("Hey! Here's the queried array of persons: " + data.json + ".");
  // Do something with each person
});
```

Here's the example app where I implement it: https://github.com/nicooga/Example-Padrino-Blog/blob/master/app/controllers/posts.rb. It's a Synatra+Padrino app but besides from the non-existence of `routes.rb` file it's pretty much the same stuff.

**EDIT:** if you don't want to perform AJAX, you can make a link with url parameters like:

```
= link_to 'Apply filter', "/MyModel?filter=true"

# MyModel_controller.rb
def method_blah
  apply_filter if params[:filter]
end
```

Comment: Thank you. That does sound like an effective solution. Your solution caused me to think about things differently. The solution I decided to use is below.